# LSTM/GRU and the use of overlapping sliding windows

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, gated-recurrent-unit

**Context**

I am currently running some experiments with *LSTMs / GRUs* in Keras. Anyhow, the following questions also relate to the general functionality of these networks, which means ***an answer does not have to be Keras-specific***.

For my experiments I choosed to predict a linear growing time series in form of a `range(10,105,5)` so that I would obviously get good results. My generator for this data follows [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-the-timeseriesgenerator-for-time-series-forecasting-in-keras/) tutorial (simply an implementation of Keras' `TimeSeriesGenerator`).

```
[[[10. 15.]
  [20. 25.]]] => [[30. 35.]]
...
[[[80. 85.]
  [90. 95.]]] => [[100. 105.]]
```

This results in `8 steps_per_epoch` and a sample of `shape (8, 1, 2, 2)`.
I then set up a simple network in Keras, which I trained over `500 epochs`:

```py
model = Sequential() 
model.add(GRU(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input, n_features), batch_size=1)) #Could also be a LSTM-layer
model.add(Dense(2)) #Following the target-shape
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

If I predict some data afterwards like this...

```py
x_input = np.array([[90, 95], [100, 105]]).reshape((1, n_input, n_features))
yhat    = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
```

... the result/prediction is `[[111.1233  116.97075]]` (good enough for the experiment -> correct is `[[110.0 115.0]]`).

**My questions**

Obviously 500 epochs is much more than needed for this amount of data.

In order to get more training data without increasing the actual data (in a real scenario this would not be possible as well) I came up with the idea of using overlapping sliding windows (the batches shown above are non-overlapping).

The batches then look like this:

```
[[[10. 15.]
  [20. 25.]]] => [[30. 35.]]
[[[15. 20.]
  [25. 30.]]] => [[35. 40.]]
[[[20. 25.]
  [30. 35.]]] => [[40. 45.]]
...
```

In theory this meant way more batches for me and I thought that the training quality would increase accordingly.

Anyhow, feeding this data to the same network results in the following prediction: `[[121.1334  134.70979]]`. Well.. these are far worse prediction results.

My questions now are:

1. Is this an expected behavior from LSTMs / GRUs? Why are overlapping windows a problem for them?
2. Is there a way to increase my data in such a way without ruining the prediction-quality?